# Identify this plant

Tags: identification

I spotted this plant while walking in Jan Marais Park in Stellenbosch, South Africa. It's currently flowering while the season is changing into spring over here. The park's information boards describe the area as renosterveld.

[image: pic]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the image and the geographic location, I believe this is likely *Polygala virgata*, a native plant of south-east Africa.
http://pza.sanbi.org/polygala-virgata
http://www.zimbabweflora.co.zw/speciesdata/species.php?species_id=133920

Comment: The leaves are different. Anyway Polygala seems a good match.